# Approach to simplify a list of dictionaries based on unique key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This case is for Python 3
I have the following list of dictionaries.

```
data = [   
 {'id': 'AAA',
  'Temperature': 1.5,
  'time_utc': 1514677434,
  'longitude': 7.278415,
  'latitude': 46.223831,
  'altitude': 479},
 {'id': 'BBB',
  'Temperature': 1.5,
  'time_utc': 1514677561,
  'longitude': 7.269399,
  'latitude': 46.21502,
  'altitude': 555},
 {'id': 'AAA',
  'Temperature': 3.4,
  'time_utc': 1514677667,
  'longitude': 7.278415,
  'latitude': 46.223831,
  'altitude': 479},
 {'id': 'BBB',
  'Temperature': 2.5,
  'time_utc': 1514677196,
  'longitude': 7.269399,
  'latitude': 46.21502,
  'altitude': 555},
]
```

The 'id' key is unique, so I want to eventually plot a time series of temperature for each 'id' (station). So the desired output is as follows:

```
data = [   
 {'id': 'AAA',
  'thermo_module': {'datetime': [{'time_utc': 1514677434}, {'time_utc': 1514677667}], 'Temperature': [1.5,3.4]}
  'longitude': 7.278415,
  'latitude': 46.223831,
  'altitude': 479},
 {'id': 'BBB',
  'thermo_module': {'datetime': [{'time_utc': 1514677561}, {'time_utc': 1514677196}], 'Temperature': [1.5,2.5]}
  'longitude': 7.269399,
  'latitude': 46.21502,
  'altitude': 555},
]
```

I really don't know how to proceed in this case, at least any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a simple iteration

**Demo:**

```
import pprint
d = {}

for i in data:
    if not i["id"] in d:
        d[i["id"]] = {'id': i["id"], 'thermo_module':{'datetime':[{'time_utc': i["time_utc"]}],  'Temperature':[i["Temperature"]]}, 'longitude':i["longitude"], 'latitude':i["latitude"], 'altitude':i["altitude"]}
    else:
        d[i["id"]]['thermo_module']["datetime"].append({'time_utc': i["time_utc"]})
        d[i["id"]]['thermo_module']["Temperature"].append(i["Temperature"])        


pprint.pprint(d.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[{'altitude': 479,
  'id': 'AAA',
  'latitude': 46.223831,
  'longitude': 7.278415,
  'thermo_module': {'Temperature': [1.5, 3.4],
                    'datetime': [{'time_utc': 1514677434},
                                 {'time_utc': 1514677667}]}},
 {'altitude': 555,
  'id': 'BBB',
  'latitude': 46.21502,
  'longitude': 7.269399,
  'thermo_module': {'Temperature': [1.5, 2.5],
                    'datetime': [{'time_utc': 1514677561},
                                 {'time_utc': 1514677196}]}}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh it works perfectly! This is the solution

Comment: @Rakesh - You can also look into collections defaultdict - no need to check if element is in the dict yet or not. Will add it on first run: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: @ScottSkiles. Thanks..I did use that(before edit) but felt like it is a little complicated for this task.

Comment: Yeah, after reading it a bit more it seemed clean due to the append. Nice one!

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll evaluate both options, because I'm working with huge data, this was just a very small example!